# Configmap in helm chart user-data

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

This is my configmap template, it is taking data from my user-data file which is like values.yaml. I have two applications, App-A & App-B. The IPs are getting assigned by App-B, in App-A only interfaces are getting configured to which App-B is assigning IPs.

CONFIGMAP Template:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: {{$namespace}}
  name: {{$pod}}-configmap
data:
  user-data: |
  {{- $userdata := (cat $pod "-userdata"|nospace)}}
  {{ $.Files.Get $userdata | nindent 4}}
```

App-A user-data

```
  ICI1: &fpbond0
    TYPE: bond
    GATEWAY: 172.57.93.129
    IFNAME: fpbond0
    PREFIX: 26
    SUBPORT: fpeth2,fpeth3
    OPTS: "mode=active-backup miimon=100 fail_over_mac=none"
    PORTTYPE: DP_PORT_TYPE_SIGNALING
    VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici1
    VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
    PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici_pip
    MTU: 1500
  ICI2:
    <<: *fpbond0
    VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici2
    VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
    
.............till ICI60
```

App-B user-data:

```
  vnfc_vldid_ici1:
    - 172.7.93.132
  vnfc_vldid_ici2:
    - 172.7.93.133
  vnfc_vldid_ici3:
    - 172.7.93.134
  vnfc_vldid_ici4:
    - 172.7.93.135

.............till ICI60
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your ip data source comes from the values.yaml file or is read from other files, the above is not clear, so here are two solutions.

---

A: from values.yaml

values.yaml

```yaml
IPs:
  ICI1: &fpbond0
    TYPE: bond
    GATEWAY: 172.57.93.1
    IFNAME: fpbond0
    PREFIX: 26
    SUBPORT: fpeth2,fpeth3
    OPTS: "mode=active-backup miimon=100 fail_over_mac=none"
    PORTTYPE: DP_PORT_TYPE_SIGNALING
    VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici1
    VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
    PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: 172.57.93.4
    MTU: 1500

  ICI2:
    <<: *fpbond0
    VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici2
    VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
    PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: 172.57.93.5

  ICI3:
    <<: *fpbond0
    VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici3
    VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
    PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: 172.57.93.6

  ICI4:
    <<: *fpbond0
    VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici4
    VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
    PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: 172.57.93.7
```

template/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: text
data:
  {{- range $.Values.IPs }}
  {{ .VIRTUAL_LINK_ID }}: {{ .PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID }}
  {{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  vnfc_vldid_ici1: 172.57.93.4
  vnfc_vldid_ici2: 172.57.93.5
  vnfc_vldid_ici3: 172.57.93.6
  vnfc_vldid_ici4: 172.57.93.7
```

---

B: from file

tree

```bash
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── prop
│   └── ips
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   └── deployment.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

prop/ips

```yaml
ICI1: &fpbond0
  TYPE: bond
  GATEWAY: 172.57.93.1
  IFNAME: fpbond0
  PREFIX: 26
  SUBPORT: fpeth2,fpeth3
  OPTS: "mode=active-backup miimon=100 fail_over_mac=none"
  PORTTYPE: DP_PORT_TYPE_SIGNALING
  VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici1
  VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
  PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: 172.57.93.4
  MTU: 1500

ICI2:
  <<: *fpbond0
  VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici2
  VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
  PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: 172.57.93.5

ICI3:
  <<: *fpbond0
  VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici3
  VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
  PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: 172.57.93.6

ICI4:
  <<: *fpbond0
  VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: vnfc_vldid_ici4
  VIRTUAL_IP_REQUIRED: True
  PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID: 172.57.93.7
```

template/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  {{- $data := .Files.Get "prop/ips" }}
  {{- $cfg := fromYaml $data }}
  {{- range $cfg }}
  {{ .VIRTUAL_LINK_ID }}: {{ .PIP_VIRTUAL_LINK_ID }}
  {{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  vnfc_vldid_ici1: 172.57.93.4
  vnfc_vldid_ici2: 172.57.93.5
  vnfc_vldid_ici3: 172.57.93.6
  vnfc_vldid_ici4: 172.57.93.7
```

Comment: I shared more details in my post

Comment: Please give your expected output, I'm still not quite sure what you want to get

Comment: basically currently I am typing all the interfaces till 62 which is making it very ugly, is there easier way like just to define a range of interfaces like u mentioned initially